# VBA: Avoid "at"-signs in my formulas when inserting

Tags: excel, vba, insert, formula

I'm trying to get my VBA code to automatically throw in a formula, if there's a value present in the A through J columns.

It works as intended, but unfortunately VBA automatically throws in a bunch of "@" signs, which makes my formula not work.

Code is pretty simple:

```
Sub INSERTFORMULAS()
    Dim sheetVARS As Worksheet
    
    Set sheetVARS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("VARS")
    
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:J").SpecialCells(2).EntireRow.Offset(1), Columns("K")).Value = "=SUMPRODUKT((" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$A$2:$A$712=J2)*(" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$B$2:$B$712=$Q$2)*(" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$D$2:$D$712))"

End Sub
```

Which results in:

```
=@SUMPRODUKT((@VARS!$A$2:$A$712=J2)*(@VARS!$B$2:$B$712=$Q$2)*(@VARS!$D$2:$D$712))
```

What I need is:

```
=SUMPRODUKT((VARS!$A$2:$A$712=J2)*(VARS!$B$2:$B$712=$Q$2)*(VARS!$D$2:$D$712))
```

Note that my Excel is in Danish, which might cause some discrepancies compared to yours.

I would really appreciate some help to this, otherwise, basic issue!

Thanks.

Comment: Does `.Formula2` instead of `.Value` fix the issue?

Comment: Not sure, but please try `...Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT((" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$A$2:$A$712=J2),(" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$B$2:$B$712=$Q$2),(" & sheetVARS.Name & "!$D$2:$D$712))"` - not SUMPRODU**K**T but English SUMPRODU**C**T, not asterisk but comma and - main! - not `.Value` but `.Formula`)

Comment: Or I guess regarding my previous comment, you would use `.Formula2Local`.